# checking for parallel completion using volatile only

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

Consider these shared flags indicating the completion of two different tasks:

```
volatile boolean completed1 = false;
volatile boolean completed2 = false;
```

Now consider two threads:

No. 1:

```
completed1 = true;
if (completed1 && completed2) continueSomeOtherStuff();
```

No. 2:

```
completed2 = true;
if (completed1 && completed2) continueSomeOtherStuff();
```

Will continueSomeOtherStuff() be reliably called at least once?

Update:

Found it in the definition of **happens-before** in http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf :

- Each action in a thread happens-before every subsequent action in that thread.
- An unlock on a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock on that monitor.
- **A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that volatile.**

No thread relation is mentioned in that last sentence so I assume it is meant to be valid across all threads.

Comment: sure, volatile will allow your threads to get the actual value of competedX var

Comment: yes, eventually, but does it ensure immediate visibility to other threads? I mean, it doesn't seem to be a lock.

Comment: yes, that is what volatile keyword do... try it and you will see

Comment: *"Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors, because any write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable. **This means that changes to a volatile variable are always visible to other threads.** What's more, it also means that when a thread reads a volatile variable, it sees not just the latest change to the volatile, but also the side effects of the code that led up the change.*" - [Atomic Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the code can be simplified as follows:

No1:

```
completed1 = true;
if (completed2) continueSomeOtherStuff();
```

No2:

```
completed2 = true;
if (completed1) continueSomeOtherStuff();
```

without changing the behavior, as the removed variables are only read by the thread that modifies them, so they are always true.

As you have declared the variables as `volatile`, it is guaranteed by the Java Memory Model that every thread immediately 'sees' modifications by other threads. This means that all caches must be invalidated and that the JVM compiler is not allowed to reorder or optimize reads of these variables.

So in your case, it is guaranteed that at the `continueSomeOtherStuff()` method is called at least once. It could also be called twice, in the rare case that both threads have executed their first assignment before both threads have evaluated the condition.